# Hive beeline conversion to Google Dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hive, google-cloud-dataproc, beeline

What will be the google cloud equivalent of `--showHeader` and `--outputformat` in Hive Beeline command.

I have the following query:

```sh
beeline -u $BEELINE_URL --showHeader=false --outputformat=vertical \
    -e "select count(*) from db.table" ;
```

I need to change this query to use Google Dataproc Jobs API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think this is supported by the Dataproc Jobs API. I filed a feature request internally. Thanks for the feedback.